# Is there a way to pass this state from component to the fetch?

Tags: reactjs

Without using any state management library, I want to pass the location state from InputsAndBtn component into the fetch in the WeatherApi() so API searches can be done with the input location. Note that they are in different files but in the same folder, how do I do this as I am stuck and I do not want to move them into one file?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { API_KEY, BASE_URL } from "./keys";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const WeatherApi = ({location}) => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`${BASE_URL}weather?q=${location}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setApiData(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return { apiData };
};

export default WeatherApi;




import { useState } from "react"
import './App.css';
import  WeatherApi  from "./api";


const InputsAndBtn = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("")
    const {apiData} = WeatherApi({ location })
    const [clouds, setClouds] = useState(null)
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(null)

    function handleChange(event) {
        setLocation(event.target.value)
    }
    function handleClouds() {
        setClouds(apiData.clouds.all)
    }
    function handleDescription() {
        setDescription(apiData.weather[0]["description"])
    }
    function handleBtn(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
            if(location === apiData.name) {
                handleClouds()
                handleDescription()
            }
    }
    return (
        <form className="form">
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                <section style={{marginRight: "auto"}}>
                    <input 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="enter a city"
                    value={location}
                    >
                    </input>
                    <button onClick={handleBtn}>Start</button>
                </section>
                {clouds && <section style={{backgroundColor: "red", width: "30vw", height: "100vh"}}>
                    <h1>{clouds}</h1>
                    <h2>{description}</h2>
                </section>}
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default InputsAndBtn
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep everything as it is, only add location as dependency to the useEffect hook [location]);

```
const WeatherApi = ({location}) => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch(....)
        .catch(....);
  }, [location]);

  return { apiData };
};
```

Comment: Add that useEffect inside the InputsAndBtn will break the code as setApiData is not defined on that page but in a separate page amongst others. Both files exist on separate pages.